# Need help syncing: WaitGroup

Tags: go, group-by, async-await, synchronization, waitgroup

I would like your help, here is a piece of code in which requests are emitted https://play.golang.org/p/1_FOY8BTZND,each request has its own delay 1 request is waiting for the second to complete, that is wg.Done(), return:

```
ID: 0, Name: Test #1, Sleep: 5ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 0, Name: Test #1, Sleep: 5ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 0, Name: Test #1, Sleep: 5ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
```

How to make the first request not wait for the second, but execute linearly, waiting only for the completion of its group, return:

```
ID: 0, Name: Test #1, Sleep: 5ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 0, Name: Test #1, Sleep: 5ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
ID: 1, Name: Test #2, Sleep: 1ns
```